# jdbc:jtds hive server 2 connection string

Tags: hive, jtds

I want to make jdbc connection to hive server through JTDS .I am not able to find proper documentation for hive jtds connection support.I am trying the following connection string
 jdbc:jtds:hive2://x.x.x.x:20000/default;user='xxx';password='xxx';

Answer (score 0):

I have used JTDS on a number of projects.

If you're using JTDS for windows authentication, you require a "ntlmauth.dll" file. This file is used for windows Authentication.

http://doc.cloveretl.com/documentation/UserGuide/index.jsp?topic=/com.cloveretl.gui.docs/docs/mssql-authentication.html

This link is quite useful incase my above explanation sounded confusing.

The connection string should be in the following format:

```
    static String URL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVERNAME:1433;"+
        "databaseName=DATABASENAME;" + // Name of database to connect to
        "useNTLMv2=true;" + // To indicate use of Windows Authentication
        "domain=DOMAINNAME\\";
```

Hope this helped